# Convert ICS into table (awk)

Tags: bash, awk, icalendar

I am trying to parse an `ics` file into a table using awk.

My ics file looks like this (only posting one event here):

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171004T173000Z
DTEND:20171004T183000Z
DTSTAMP:20180209T144026Z
UID:999999c@google.com
CREATED:20171004T171653Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20171004T173916Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:This text is the summary
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:NONE
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z
X-WR-ALARMUID:282393849382
UID:883928394839283948392
ACKNOWLEDGED:20171004T173915Z
X-APPLE-DEFAULT-ALARM:TRUE
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

I am only interested in the lines starting with `DTSTART`, `DTEND`, `CREATED`, `SUMMARY`.

I came up with the following code

```
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
$1=="DTSTART"{DTSTART=$2}
$1=="DTEND"{DTEND=$2}
$1=="CREATED"{CREATED=$2}
$1=="SUMMARY"{SUMMARY=$2}
{print DTSTART DTEND CREATED SUMMARY}
```

that I am executing with

```
awk -F":" -f ics.awk file.ics
```

but there seems to be an error somewhere.
Plus, it would be nice to print a table header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution (for static input file format):

```
awk -F':' '$1~/^(DTSTART|DTEND|CREATED|SUMMARY)/{ 
               printf "%s%s",$2,($1=="SUMMARY"? ORS:"\t") 
          }' file.ics
```

The output:

```
20171004T173000Z    20171004T183000Z    20171004T171653Z    This text is the summary
```

Comment: I have to pipe `perl -pe 's/\r//g'`, then it works perfectly

Comment: Watch out that the order of entries in a vevent does not change, otherwise you'll be in for a surprise.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, read my 1st sentence again - (**for static input file format**)

Answer (score 4):

Just replace the last line with

```
/^END:VEVENT/ {print DTSTART, DTEND, CREATED, SUMMARY}
```

and the first by

```
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
  print "DTSTART", "DTEND", "CREATED", "SUMMARY"
}
```

Result:

```
DTSTART DTEND   CREATED SUMMARY
20171004T173000Z    20171004T183000Z    20171004T171653Z    This text is the summary
```

You were executing "{print DTSTART DTEND CREATED SUMMARY}" for every line.

Comment: forgot the commas in the print